# Dealing with interrupted audio file download

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, network-programming, core-audio

I am downloading a audio file from a server, which I then want to play. However, during the file download, some data may be lost due to network fluctuations (network comes and goes), resulting in an incomplete or missing file. Therefore, when I play the downloaded file, my app crashes.

Is there any way to only re-download the missing part of the file when I play it?

Answer (score 1):

Immediately before playing the audio file, check if the file exists. If not, instead of 
playing it show an alert message that the file has not been downloaded yet. In the alert message you could ask the user, "Do you want to download the file again?"

Comment: Thank you very much Amit Sinha

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The situation here is say the user paid some money to download the file for the first time and due to network fluctuations some data is lost. So we can't ask the user to again pay for the audio. Instead user must be allowed to re-download the audio but for free. Do you have any solution for this?